# Функция LISTAGG возвращает крякозабры

Tags: oracle, кодировка

Есть данные:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | а |
| 1 | б |
| 1 | с |
| 2 | д |

Так все отображается правильно:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
```

Но если использую функцию `LISTAGG`, то вижу непонятные квадратики вместо кириллицы:

```
SELECT 
ID, LISTAGG(TYPE, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) "product_listing"
FROM t1
GROUP BY ID
```

Например, вместо слова "Аренда" я вижу символы: @5=40

Из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

При чем, я заметила, что если я сама задаю значение, например:

```
with t1 as (
select 1 as id, 'х' as type from dual
union all
select 1 as id, 'Аренда' as type from dual
union all
select 1 as id, 'y' as type from dual
union all
select 2 as id, 'z' as type from dual
) 
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(TYPE, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) "product_listing"
FROM t1
GROUP BY ID
```

, то все будет отображаться правильно.

Comment: Какая у вас кодировка в БД? Колонка type какого типа?

Comment: @0xdb тип колонки type NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR) 
если я не ошибаюсь где смотреть кодировку БД, то NLS_CHARACTERSET - CL8MSWIN1251

Comment: Вы уверены, что NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR)? Для  NVARCHAR2 нельзя указать  CHAR или BYTE, этот тип всегда CHAR.

Comment: Попробуйте явно конвертировать в varchar2: `LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (TYPE), '; ')`.

Comment: Спасибо  LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(TYPE), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)  помогло

Comment: Рад был помочь! Попозже оформлю ответом с пояснениями, почему так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение: явно конвертировать функцией [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-character.html#GUID-EC078E16-11FE-4ABE-AE05-DA9AC1B4BEBC) символы юникодов из кодировки AL16UTF16 в кодировку БД (в вопросе CL8MSWIN1251):

```
SELECT ID, LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (TYPE), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) "product_listing"
FROM t1
GROUP BY ID
```

---

В данном случае, тип колонки `type NVARCHAR2`. В документации [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) не специфицированы входные типы данных, только тип возврата:

> The *measure_expr* is the measure column and can be any expression. [...]
> If the measure column is of type RAW, then the return data type is RAW. Otherwise, the return data type is VARCHAR2.

Повидимому, при передаче как параметр не происходит неявного преобразования колонки `type` из типа `NVARCHAR2` в `VARCHAR2` (возможно баг). То есть, *перекодировки символов не происходит*, как в упрощённом примере:

```
select col,
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_raw.cast_to_raw (col)) res
from (select n'Аренда' col from dual);
```

Результат полностью идентичен тому, как в вопросе, его привожу скрином, т.к. некоторые спез.символы не отображаются текстом  на сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS В последнем примере вопроса тоже не будет работать, если задать литерал правильно - `n'Аренда'` вместо `'Аренда'`.